# Show buddypress notification in the frontend

Tags: buddypress

I've a buddypress website and what I want is to show in the frontend the notification that buddybar have in the backend, but only the notification not all the buddybar.

basically set the notification like facebook....

how can I do that?

Comment: Hi, Manuele, welcome to WPSE! Please, try to add more details to your Question, a screenshot, relevant code (if you can locate it). Take a look at this guide: [ask].

Comment: Hi not sure if this is what you are trying to do, if you go to http://smeak.com you can see it at work, we split the notifications intro 3, and into a custom toolbar we built for the network. Let me know to see if we can help

Answer (score 2):

Put the following code in your functions.php. If you want a demo i can show you.

```
// my custom notification menu www.cityflavourmagazine.com

function my_bp_adminbar_notifications_menu() {
global $bp;

if ( !is_user_logged_in() )
    return false;

echo '<li id="top-notification">';
_e( 'Alerts', 'buddypress' );

if ( $notifications = bp_core_get_notifications_for_user( $bp->loggedin_user->id ) ) { ?>
    <span><?php echo count( $notifications ) ?></span>
<?php
}

echo '</a>';
echo '<ul>';

if ( $notifications ) {
    $counter = 0;
    for ( $i = 0; $i < count($notifications); $i++ ) {
        $alt = ( 0 == $counter % 2 ) ? ' class="alt"' : ''; ?>

        <li<?php echo $alt ?>><?php echo $notifications[$i] ?></li>

        <?php $counter++;
    }
} else { ?>

    <li><a href="<?php echo $bp->loggedin_user->domain ?>"><?php _e( 'You have no new alerts.', 'buddypress' ); ?></a></li>

<?php
}

echo '</ul>';
echo '</li>';
}
```

Use the following code to call it anywhere you like. Note: you can amend the above code as you like

`<?php my_bp_adminbar_notifications_menu()?>`

Answer (score 1):

look at this page 
http://www.colegeissinger.com/blog/2012/12/04/get-buddypress-notifications-count/
where he explains like below:

Put that function into your functions.php file

```
    function cg_current_user_notification_count() {
    $notifications = bp_core_get_notifications_for_user(bp_loggedin_user_id(), 'object');
    $count = !empty($notifications) ? count($notifications) : 0;

    echo $count;
     }
```

in front end use,

```
Notificaitons : <?php cg_current_user_notification_count(); ?>
```