# How can I display list of notifications of buddypress in a single page or post

Tags: buddypress

I need to display the notifications that come on hover of the notification in one page I tried to follow this [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84072/show-buddypress-notification-in-the-frontend) but I cannot make it Please guid me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `[activity-stream ]` to display notifications